# Определить когда заканчивается action в yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

Вообщем такая проблема, я на странице делаю отправку формы, через плагин mpdf у меня формируется документ и я возвращаю файл который человек сохраняет, проблема в том, что пока документ формируется может пройти некоторое время, и человек может снова нажать кнопку, да я могу её заблокировать, но как поймать конец этого формирования, чтобы разблокировать кнопку. Для формирования документа использую отдельный action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать отправку формы AJAX.

После отправки разумеется кнопку блокируйте. Когда же обработка на сервере закончится, будет вызвано событие в обработчике которого Вы сможете разблокировать кнопку.

Пример на jQuery для обработчика события `beforeSubmit` формы:

```
$.ajax({
     // Метод отправки данных (тип запроса)
     type : 'post',
     // URL для отправки запроса
     url : my_url,
     // Данные формы
     data : my_data
}).done(function(data) {
    if (data.error == null) {
        // Если ответ сервера успешно получен                    
    } else {
        // Если при обработке данных на сервере произошла ошибка                    
    }
}).fail(function() {
    // Если произошла ошибка при отправке запроса            
})
```

Вызовы метода `on` и `documentReady` здесь опущены.

Более полный пример, который иллюстрирует основные принципы работы с AJAX в Yii можно посмотреть в частности [здесь](http://streletzcoder.ru/rabotaem-s-ajax-v-yii-2/).